# How to redirect a user after a notify url gets hit in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, notifications

I am looking for some direction. 
I have a Django project with a fair amount of views. What I need to do is redirect a given user to a success URL after a task has been completed by an external application.

What I've done so far is set up a view with its corresponding entry in urls.py

```
# views.py
def notifyURL(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/success_page/')
```

notifyURL is hit by an external app I've written using a simple GET request. However it seems that Django won't redirect the browser but the calling (headless) application.

How should I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not really possible via 'redirect'.

You can only redirect a user at the point where that user makes a request. If the user has made a request and received a response, you cannot later 'redirect' the user in response to some other event happening later in the backend.

What you need is some way for the backend Django app to notify the frontend (i.e. Javascript app) that an event has occurred and the user should be forwarded, by javascript, to a new url.

There are two approaches:

1. 'polling' - where the javascript periodically contacts the back end, eg with a `setInterval` timer requesting to a status url via ajax. This is probably the easiest to implement with Django.
2. 'push' - where the backend contacts the frontend directly... this basically means using WebSockets, which is not so easy with Django (or any WSGI python web framework). See this for help though https://django-omnibus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Right. Thanks for the tips. However, how should django itself be notified that the a task is complete? The tasks are not processed by django at all but by an external web app.

Comment: @Konos5 basically, call a url on the django app, see my answer to similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24269158/202168

Comment: Thanks. I tried a customized version of yours and works fine. However how should Django notify the *appropriate* user when its task is complete? (I don't mind about polling or progress for now - I just need some sort of signal to the proper destination). Is django-notification any relevant?

Comment: Thanks. Polling did the trick. However, what if I didn't have to 'notify the frontend'? What if when an external event occured I'd have to just delete a key from a particular user's session? How should I approach that? message-passing through a file maybe..?

Comment: @Konos5 I'd probably set a flag on the db. Depending on whether you just need to notify the user something occurred, or you need to take other actions, you may be able to use Django's messages framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/  ...it allows you to set a message for a particular user which will be displayed to them on their next page request